# Magento CE 2.3.1 Product Import issue

Tags: magento2, import, csv

I am facing issue import Magento stock source importing. please check the snapshot

> Upload CSV:
>
> ***https://prnt.sc/ranqvc***

and getting error snapshot:

> ***https://prnt.sc/ranr13***

Below my CSV format please help me how to solve the issue thanks in advance

> Please check my CSV:
>   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FXhgtGK5sFo9kIXnQUKjKJ_LvHX0SLWu/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think but not sure. you try this solution i think help this solution.

Please your csv set the this type : -

1. sku
2. status
3. quantity
4. source_code

And check the screen-short :-

> https://prnt.sc/raof16

Comment: hi Mohit I alredy tried both two options add/update and replace not working  for me csv looking okay

Answer (score 0):

In Issued First You try the 100 row to import product at a one time because some time there are large row to import product was not working.

so try the 100 100 rows to import products.

And Also When you import product the one field is error

https://prnt.sc/rao65p

Comment: I tried but it is not working for me , can you please help me with any alternatives

Comment: Have You got The Answer Of Your Quation

Answer (score 0):

I tried as per your advice issue remain same can you help me with any alternative

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help i have already tried the the two option